# fetching the records from oracle database on the basis of query

Tags: database, oracle

I have an table employee which consists of a filed date in which date is store in this format

```
19.10.13 10:50:56.464
```

Now sometimes  I need to fetch the records from the employee table on the basis of date in which the value of date is known to me, such as I want to fetch all the records of the employee table on the basis of date and date is 19.10.13 10:50:56.464 , please advise what will be the query for oracle database as I am trying this but it s giving exception..

```
select * from employee where date ='19.10.13 10:50:56.464'
```

well in DDL the date is define as shown below..

```
date  TIMESTAMP(6)   NOT NULl
```

Comment: @Mureinik Have done that please see the updated post

Comment: what exception dooes oracle return?

Answer (score 4):

`timestamp` (and `date`) columns do **not** store the value in any specific format. Whatever format you see is applied by your SQL client tool after the value has been retrieved.

Your comparison

```
where date = '19.10.13 10:50:56.464'
```

relies on implicit data type conversion which only works if the format you give is the same as the current NLS format used by your SQL client (and the database). When comparing timestamp (or date) columns you should always specify "real" timestamp (or date) *literals*.

The most robust (and shortest) to specify a timestamp literal is to use the ANSI literal format:

```
select * 
from employee 
where date = timestamp '2013-10-19 10:50:56.464'
```

An ANSI timestamp literal is introduced with the keyword `timestamp` followed by a string where the date is formatted as an ISO timestamp. The time part must be supplied in a 24 hour format when using ANSI literals.

Btw: `date` is a horrible name for a column. Firstly because it's also the name of a datatype. And secondly (and more important): it doesn't document what the column contains. Is it the "hire date", the "date of birth", the "leave date", the "last vaction date"? You should really consider finding a better name for that.

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d93a1/1)

```
select * 
from employee
where date = to_timestamp('13.10.13 10:50:56.464','DD.MM.YY HH24:MI:SS.FF3')
```

Convert your input into a timestamp and compare it.